# Negative slope in QGIS

Tags: qgis, slope, tobler

How do I use the QGIS slope function to calculate slope and differentiate between uphill and downhill, and produce both positive and negative slopes?

Comment: Do you have a direction raster/vector? A sloppy zone can be uphill/downhill area, it depends on the reference's direction

Comment: A slope doesn't have uphill and downhill per se. You can only have up or down relative to "something". Are you trying to identify hills vs valleys?

Comment: was trying to have the hiking speed acc to Tobler go faster or slower pending on the slope which includes up and down hill from each bus station